# How to center this <nav> element navigation bar of no width

Tags: css, navigation

I am having some problem with centering this horizontal navigation bar. Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W796k/embedded/result/
I'm looking for two things:
1. How can I center the navigation bar horizontally without putting a specified width?
2. How to further add some more 'li' in the 'ul' so that all the 'li's wil be squeezed automatically to make room for the new added 'li's in the navigation bar?

Have I made everything clear? Ask me if you need more info. Thank U all in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<Doctype! html>

<html>

<head>
<title> horizontal dropdown menu </title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">

    a{
        font-family: "verdana", sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    nav ul{
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
        background: #efefef;
        background: linear-gradient (top,#efefef,#bbbbbb);
        background: moz-linear-gradient (top, #efefef,#bbbbbb);
        background: webkit-linear-gradient (top,#efefef,#bbbbbb);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        padding: 0 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: inline-table;
    }
    nav ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    nav ul li:hover{
        background: #5b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }
    nav ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul li:hover a{
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    nav ul ul{
        background: #5f6975;
        border-radius: 0; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul{
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul ul li{
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        border-right: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav ul ul li a{
        padding: 10px 40px;
    }
    nav ul ul li a:hover{
        background: #4b545f;
    }
    nav ul ul ul{
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Works &#8595 </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Photoshop </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Illustrator  </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Web Design &#8594 </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"> HTML </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> CSS </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> Downloads &#8595 </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Softwares </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Ebooks </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> About Us </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did none of the answers below help you or you just forgot to accept or comment on any answer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
 nav { text-align: center }
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO,

```
nav { margin: 0 auto;}
```

Explanation: "0" will set the "margin-top" & "margin-bottom" to zero. And "auto" property will set left and right margins equally thus setting nav to the centre;

Answer (score 1):

Apply this style:

```
nav{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W796k/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use:

```
nav { text-align: center }
```

In your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a table instead of list. If you are using list, giving width will not set your added list items as you are wishing.

1 & 2.making it center without giving a specific width can be avoided using the table.Give a width to your table and there will be no problem even if you add an extra element to your table.It will auto adjust in the given width with out disturbing your layout.

Comment: Please see the other answer of the same page

Answer (score 0):

Simply have this line of code in your stylesheet.

```
nav { 
  text-align: center 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;` will do the magic for you..

Answer (score 0):

the following will be the css

```
*{
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
 }

nav table{
border-spacing: 10px 0; 
}    
.make-block{
position:relative;
}
nav table td span{
clear:both;
text-decoration: none;
display: table-cell;
white-space: nowrap;
position:relative;
 }

 nav table td:hover{
background: #000;
color:#fff;
 } 


nav table td dl {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}

nav table td:hover dl{
display: block;
}

dd{
padding-right: 20px;
background: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
}

ul.l1 li{
clear: both;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:10px;
padding: 5px 0;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.l1{
display: table-cell;
padding: 6px;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

the following is the mark-up that you can use.

```
<nav>
<table>
<td>
<div class="make-block">
    <span>a</span>
        <dl>
            <dd>
                <ul class="l1">     
                    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </dd>
        </dl>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="make-block">
    <span>b</span>
        <dl>
            <dd>
                <ul class="l1">     
                    <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </dd>
        </dl>
</div>
</td>
</table>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a{
  font-family: "verdana", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background: #5b545f;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li:hover a{
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul ul{
  background: #5f6975;
  border-radius: 0; padding: 0;
  position: absolute; top: 100%;
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
nav ul ul li{
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  border-right: 0;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a{
  padding: 10px 40px;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
  background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul{
  position: absolute; left: 100%; top: 0;
}

/* flexbox */
nav {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;  

  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;       
}

nav ul {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;       

  -webkit-align-self: center;       
  align-self: center;
}
/* || flexbox */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Works &#8595 </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Photoshop </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Illustrator  </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Web Design &#8594 </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> HTML </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> CSS </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Downloads &#8595 </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> Softwares </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Ebooks </a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> About Us </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```